# Place background behind img in div

Tags: html, css, sass

So, I have img inside div like this:

```
<div class="row text-center about__gallery">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="about__gallery--first img">
      <img />
    </div>
  </div>
   .
   .
   .
</div>
```

The effect I want to achieve is to have div with color exactly the same size as img behind it (on hover I'm gonna move img a little bit).
SCSS looks like this:

```
.about__gallery{
  margin-top: 5%;
  .img{
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    width:70%;
    height:230px;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
    img{
      z-index: 3;
    }
    &:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: " ";
      display: block;
      width: 70%;
      height: 230px;
      background-color: $color-blue;
      z-index: -100;
    }
  }
  .about__gallery--first{
    margin-left: 45%;
    img{
      content:url("../img/aboutus_pic1.png");
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  .
  .
```

Unfortunately result looks like this: DELETED DUE TO REPUTATION

Edit with full code:

```
<div class="row text-center about__gallery">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="about__gallery--first img">
      <img class="about__gallery__img--bg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="about__gallery--second img">
      <img class="about__gallery__img--bg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="about__gallery--third img">
      <img class="about__gallery__img--bg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my full .scss looks like this:

```
.about__gallery{
margin-top: 5%;
margin-bottom: 10%;
.img {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    &:before {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      content: " ";
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: $color-blue;
      z-index: -100;
    }
}

.about__gallery--first{
     margin-left: 45%;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     img.about__gallery__img--bg{
       content:url("../img/aboutus_pic1.png");
       width: 100%;
     }
   }
   .about__gallery--second{
     margin:auto;
     img.about__gallery__img--bg{
       content:url("../img/aboutus_pic2.png");
       width: 100%;
     }
   }
   .about__gallery--third{
     margin-left: -15%;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     img.about__gallery__img--bg{
       content:url("../img/aboutus_pic3.png");
       width: 100%;
     }
   }
   }
```

And now my page looks like this:[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBt57.jpg)

My goal is to have something like that on my site:[GOAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48WLO.png)

Added hover that doesn't work........ 
codepen.io/Kreha/pen/vmbzPb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things I would do.  First, remove the static height/widths that you have set.  Let the container inherit them from the image.  Then, you'll need to set the top/left position of the pseudo element, relative to the position of your container (which should be set to relative).  [Here's a working example](https://codepen.io/jmsessink/pen/eWbGrb).

```
<div class="row text-center about__gallery">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="about__gallery--first img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.about__gallery {
    margin-top: 5%;

    .img {
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 15%;

        img {
            opacity: 0.8; // just to show the blue behind it
            width: 100%; 
            height: auto;
        }

        &:before {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            content: " ";
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: $color-blue;
            z-index: -100;
        }
    }

    &--first {
        margin-left: 45%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn that works really nice.........but only for one picture for some reason :( I have 2 more in the same row and they are messed up. I'm going to add my full code. I would be really grateful if you could help me with this.

Comment: I've updated the [codepen](https://codepen.io/jmsessink/pen/eWbGrb) with more images in the row.  I removed the left margin on the first col img because it is not semantically correct to have that with the grid (it'll mess with the image size).  I also set the image width with a variable and am using it to center align the background color in the column with `left : 50%; margin-left: -(half of the image width)px;`

Comment: Feel free to set up a codepen with a more detailed usage of what you have, because it's difficult to really see what you're trying to achieve (with the margins and position) without the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

When i do css stuff i usually use Chrome Inspect Element to locate that particular element and try to change it's bg color and on the right side of CIE see css tab where you can see which class specifically is being effected so just simply call that class in your internal or external file and use an image as a background, hope it helps!

I changed the bg color of this current page we are working on, hehe!

```
.so-header~.container {
background-color: #ccc;
}
```